# Incrementing dict values with dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, ternary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to do the following expression with dict comprehension and a ternary operation in python:

```
for num in ar:
     if num in seen_dict:
         seen_dict[num] += 1
     else:
         seen_dict[num] = 1
```

I tried this:

```
seen_dict = { num: seen_dict[num] += 1 for num in ar if num in seen_dict else seen_dict[num] = 1}
```

and several permutations thereof, but I keep getting syntax errors. Is it possible to do what I want?

**UPDATE**

This is the correct syntax, but not my dict only comes back with 1's:
`seen_dict = { num: (seen_dict[num] + 1) if num in seen_dict else 1 for num in ar }`

Can someone explain why this doesn't function the same way as the for loop? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot use assignment or increment operators in a dictionary comprehension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't. It *seems* like using dict comprehensions for this should be a good idea, but it's actually a horrible trap. Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import counts

seen_dict = collections.Counter(ar)
```

or if you don't want to do that, then stick with the loop.

The problem with trying to use a dict comprehension is that a dict comprehension has no good way to maintain state or interleave the computation of the values of each key. Each value must be computed in a single expression. In contrast, the best way to solve your counting problem is to make a single pass over `ar` and update each element's count as you go.

The restrictions of a comprehension lead to horribly inefficient attempts like

```
seen_dict = {val: ar.count(val) for val in ar}
```

which makes a number of passes over `ar` equal to the length of `ar`, or the slightly more efficient but still horribly suboptimal

```
seen_dict = {val: ar.count(val) for val in set(ar)}
```

which only needs to make `len(set(ar))` passes, or for people [a bit more familiar with the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby),

```
from itertools import groupby
seen_dict = {val: sum(1 for _ in group) for val, group in groupby(sorted(ar))}
```

which at least isn't quadratic time, but is still O(nlogn) for a length-n `ar`.

If we [run a timing](https://ideone.com/kjHBYJ) of these four snippets with input `list(range(10000))`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
from timeit import timeit

ar = list(range(10000))

print(timeit('Counter(ar)', number=1, globals=globals()))
print(timeit('{val: ar.count(val) for val in ar}', number=1, globals=globals()))
print(timeit('{val: ar.count(val) for val in set(ar)}', number=1, globals=globals()))
print(timeit('{val: sum(1 for _ in group) for val, group in groupby(sorted(ar))}',
             number=1, globals=globals()))
```

We get the following output:

```
0.0005530156195163727
1.0503493696451187
1.0463058911263943
0.00422721728682518
```

`Counter` finishes in half a millisecond, while the `count` snippets both take over a second. (The `set` version seems to have a lower runtime due to some sort of first-run effect slowing down the other version; swapping the order of the `set` and non-`set` version usually reverses the relative timing of those versions. The deduplication of `set` doesn't help in this test, since the input has no duplicates.)

For a longer input, relying on `count` would be even more prohibitively expensive. Relying on `count` could easily take days for an input that `Counter` would still finish in under a second.

Comment: Calling it a horrible trap is hilarious. 

Thank you for this answer.

Comment: I'm interested in why the set finished faster than the normal list, as `ar` has only distinct values.

Comment: @teclnol: Probably just unrelated timing variations. The `set` call is only a tiny fraction of the runtime for that input; almost all of the runtime is spent on `count` calls.

Comment: After some more testing, it looks too consistent to be random variation. It looks more like the one that goes first having to do more work somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here, it was actually way simpler than I thought. Basically what you want is the amount of times something occurs in the list, which you can do by saying `ar.count(num)`. You can easily do this without ternary operators like so:

```
ar = [1,2,3,2]
seen_dict = { num:ar.count(num) for num in ar}
print(seen_dict)# {1:1, 2:2, 3:1}
```

Comment: This is extremely inefficient (a property common to most attempts to use dict comprehensions to perform aggregation). Every `count` call requires a complete pass over `arr`.

Comment: I see, while it is inefficient it is doing what the op asked.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're trying to get the appearances of all values in a list. (If it's not, please let me know.) Here's how I would approach that:

```
seen_dict = {num: arr.count(num) for num in list(set(arr))}
```

An explanation:

- `arr.count(num)`: the `list.count(element)` method returns the number of appearances of `element` in `list`
- `set(arr)`: creates a `set` object, which when converted back to a list removes all duplicates, or in other words, gets all distinct values of a list
- `list(set(arr))`: the distinct values in `arr`

The dictionary return would have key-value pairs of `number`-`# of appearances of number in arr`.

Comment: Wow we got the same answer at the same time.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient (a property common to most attempts to use dict comprehensions to perform aggregation). Every `count` call requires a complete pass over `arr`.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Is there another way to do it without so many passes over the original `arr`?

Comment: It turns out that using dict comprehensions for this is just a horrible trap. It seems like it should be a good idea at first, but a dict comprehension will never be as efficient as a normal loop for this.

Comment: Thank you for all the useful feedback! Both the .count method answer and the explanation of why that would be inefficient!